# Does it imply $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R?$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be such that $\forall~x\in\mathbb R$$$
\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{h}$$exist. Does it imply $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R?$

Comment: This is very similar to [symmetric derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative). There is quite an extensive literature about it - some references can be found in the Wikipedia article. If you have a look in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?q=symmetric+derivative) and 
[Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=symmetric+derivative) you can see that it is mentioned in many places.

Comment: Just to add, if $f'(x)$ exists then this limit also exists and is equal to $f'(x)$. But existence of this limit does not imply the existence of derivative. The reason is that the derivative depends in an essential way on the value $f(x)$. This limit handles values of $f$ near $x$ but not at $x$.

Answer (score 10):

No, it does not. Suppose that $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \ne 0$, and $f(0) = 0$. It's fairly easy to check that for every $x$, we have

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{h} = 0$$

even though $f$ isn't even continuous.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't $[x]$ another example?

Comment: Nice example ;) I will delete mine!

Comment: @ceaser No. The relevant limit doesn't exit at, for example, $x = 1$.

Comment: The absolute value function is also a nice example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the characteristic function of the rationals (i.e. $f(x) = 1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise). For any rational $x$ and any real $h$, $f(x+h) = f(x-h)$ so the limit is 0: this function has a symmetric derivative at every rational. Yet this function is nowhere continuous let alone differentiable.