# If $f $ is diﬀerentiable in $x_0 \epsilon R$, does $lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x_0 + h) − f(x_0 − h)}{ 2h}$ exist? is the converse true?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I used taylor expansion to figure out that the limit exists and is equal to $f'(x_0)$. However does the converse of this statement hold?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it imply $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R?$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582838/does-it-imply-f-is-differentiable-on-mathbb-r)

Comment: Or this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594167/if-lim-h-to-0-fracfx-0-h-fx-0-h2h-fx-0-exists-is-f-dif.